# Dynamic Excel Chart based on Data Validation Dropdown

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts

I am trying to get a chart to adjust based on a given input, e.g., data validation dropdown. I have QTD, YTD, 1 Year, 3 Year, etc. If I select YTD in the dropdown, I want the chart data to lookup the range based on the "YTD" selection, and only select the number of rows YTD. If the user selects from the dropdown "3 Year" I want the graph to show the last 3 years of data. How do I do this? I already have named ranges for each range, e.g., QTD, YTD, 1 year, etc, but I can't get the Chart series to reference the cell that references the named range.

Comment: How is your data arranged? In principle this isn't hard, but the way to approach it depends a lot on the data layout.

Comment: I figured it out -- what was happening was there were a lot of "#N/As" and the chart couldn't read them, e.g., if I selected 1 year but the sheet I was referencing had 520 rows, there would be 470 rows of #N/A. By adding an iferror and using the NA() function, the N/As were no longer problematic and the chart would read the data and disregard the #N/As.

Comment: The NA() function returns an #N/A error. Perhaps what was in the worksheet was some kind of text that looked like the #N/A error, but was treated as text by the chart.